# How to extract or view data from a .dat file?

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, jet

I have a directory with the following files: 
`Data.dat`
`Data.ldb`
`Program.exe`
`prog.UDL`

I want to access the data in Data.dat which is 82mb large
Any solution?

I tried to run the program but it throws an error that it cannot connect to database. I was wondering if there is a way to access the data.dat file and view the data. When I try to open it with a text editor it looks like this:

[image]
I managed to view the file with MDB Viewer Plus and this is what I'm getting; a list of tables with this sort of encrypted data:

[image]

Comment: As long as you don't know which data format the `.dat` file is you cannot read it. A `.dat` file can be anything you cannot tell the data format from the file extension. You will probably need to read that file with the original program that created the file.

Comment: Have you just tried changing the extension to .mdb? _Standard Jet DB_ hints at a plain old mdb file, but Access might complain if the extension is wrong. The presence of an ldb file hints that it got closed incorrectly and might suffer from corruption.

Comment: Don't forget to backup your files before!

Comment: I tried to change the extension to .mdb it seems to open it but shows only one table not the rest of the data, btw the db is created in 2005

Comment: Actually this is not a question about programming and therefore [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."*

Answer (score 1):

I looked around a bit and stumbled across this Visual Basic code here.

```
Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
              "Data Source=C:\Docs\db1.dat;"

Set cat.ActiveConnection = cn

For Each t In cat.Tables
    strList=t.Name & vbcrlf & strList
Next 

MsgBox strList
```

Here's the [Forum Link](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1544710)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to view any readable content from the file without any structure, a *nix environment includes a program called 'strings' which will output the printable character strings from a file and filter out the rest.

I you're running Windows, sysinternals provides the same utility:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/strings